# Does a bedroom without ventilation violate code?

Tags: vent, bedroom, heat, air

I have a bedroom that has no heat/air vent. The room is approximately 120 square feet. Is this a code violation (I live in Utah) and how necessary is it for me to have at least one vent?

Comment: Does it have an exhaust fan? An openable window?

Comment: No exhaust fan, but yes, a window that opens.

Comment: Oops, I was thinking of bathroom - there is a rule for bathrooms of "must have openable window of a certain size or an exhaust fan". But that's for getting stuff out, not for heating. Have to see what I can find about that.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a "vent" to provide room heating, and I've never heard of a building code that required one. If you have any electrical outlets in the room, a small electrical heater will provide ample heating. There are many designs to choose from. Old houses were quite commonly built with no "central heat", and small portable devices were moved around as necessary, or they had wood or coal stoves and a chimney connection (likely long since covered over). Sometimes heat was provided by convection from a grilled opening in the floor to a lower room that had a heat source.